# Combine two methods into one

Tags: java, spring, http

What's the best method for converting these two methods into one?

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<String> dbStatus() {
        return statusService.isDbAlive() ? RESPONSE_DB_UP : RESPONSE_DB_DOWN;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<String> appStatus() throws IOException {
        return statusService.isAppAlive() ? RESPONSE_APP_UP : RESPONSE_APP_DOWN;
    }
```

Could I return a `List` of `ResponseEntity<String>`?

Comment: Explain what you're trying to do. The above will throw errors on initialization. A `List<ResponseEntity<String>>` is not a return type supported by default and doesn't make sense if you understand what a `ResponseEntity` is.

Comment: I am trying to check both db and app status from the `StatusService` class and return the statuses of both, preferably as a `ResponseEntity<String>`. I want only one `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)` to be called instead of two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to return something like JSON showing the result of both checks. For example

```
{"isAppAlive" : true, "isDbAlive": false}
```

You can build this JSON string yourself

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<String> getStatus() throws IOException {
    String json = "{\"isAppAlive\":" + statusService.isAppAlive() + ",\"isDbAlive\""+ statusService.isDbAlive() +"}";
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(json, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Or build a class like

```
public class Status {
    // use private and getters/setters
    public boolean isAppAlive;
    public boolean isDbAlive; 
}
```

and let Spring serialize the `Status` object you  create

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Status> getStatus() throws IOException {
    Status status = new Status();
    status.isAppAlive = statusService.isAppAlive();
    status.isDbAlive = statusService.isDbAlive();
    return new ResponseEntity<Status>(status, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

You can always make `statusService` have a method `getStatus()` that returns a `Status` object that already has its fields set already.

Your client can then parse the JSON and check each status.

Answer (score 0):

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/testurl",
       method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
  public ModelAndView dbStatus() {

             List<String>  status = new ArrayList<String>();
             status.add (statusService.isDbAlive() );
             status.add (statusService.isAppAlive() );
             ModelMap modelMap = new ModelMap();
             modelMap.put("status ", status );
             return new ModelAndView("statuspage.jsp", modelMap);

  }
```

Comment: It would be nice if we could at least tell which element in the list maps to which status.